# How to add banner in Opencart 3

Tags: opencart-3

How to add banner in Opencart 3 between featured products.like in the screenshot[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To add banner in the storefront

1. Go to design/banner in the admin panel
2. click on add new banner option
3. Select Image/Images
4. Enter the title and link and save it.

Now go to Extensions/Extensions and select module from the list

1. Click add on banner Module
2. Select the banner name and fill all the required fields such as height and width.
3. Enable it and save it

Now go to design/layout

1. select layout
2. apply the module in the selected position
3. Save it

That's it now you can see your banner image in a storefront 
Hope the answer to the question.

Comment: how to remove featured name.